# JBoss AS 7 + Spring + JPA EntityManager nullpointer exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, entitymanager

I work on this for a while. I want to use OpenShift for my public server. So locally I use JBoss AS 7 too. I read a lot of forums, some similar issues, but none of them solved my problem.
I use JPA , Spring 3, hibernate. I think I have something wrong in the springDispatcher-servlet.xml.

What is the issue?! In the DAO, where I use EntityManager, I get nullpointerException when I want to use a query on that. However the entityManager itself is not null.
Let me show you, what I have.

Part of my springDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
           <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="primary"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.db" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

I want to use the datasource what gives my the jboss in the standalone.xml. So I use the persistence.xml for settings. Here is the persistenceUnitName given in the ..-servlet.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have database connection. It creates the annotated table at start because of the "create-drop" setting above. So it is good.

The classes under the com.company.db package are very simple:

DAO interface:

```
   public interface LocationDAO {

    public List<Location> getList();

}
```

DAO implementation:

```
    @Repository("locationDAO")
public class LocationDAOImpl implements LocationDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Location> getList() {
        List<Location> retVal = new ArrayList<Location>();

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select l from Location l");
        if (query != null) {
            retVal = query.getResultList();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    };

}
```

Here is the problem. When calls createQuery from entityManager (entityManager is not null).

My transaction interface:

```
  public interface LocationDataService {

    public List<Location> getLocations();

}
```

And the implementation:

```
 @Service("locationDataService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class LocationDataServiceImpl implements LocationDataService {

    @Autowired
    private LocationDAO locationDAO;

    public LocationDataServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        List<Location> retVal = new ArrayList<Location>();

        retVal = locationDAO.getList();

        return retVal;
    }

}
```

And I almost forgot the Location class:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "post_code")
    private String postCode;

    public Location() {

    }

    public Location(Integer id, String country, String city, String postCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }



 //getters, setters are here
}
```

Do you have any suggestions, what I have missed in the configuration?

It would be very helpful, because I think I need just a bit modification at this point.

This is the stacktrace:

```
14:10:16,924 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[springDispatcher]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet springDispatcher threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:73) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1207) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:176) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:125) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:120) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:423) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:485) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at $Proxy38.createEntityManager(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:195) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:211) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at $Proxy39.createQuery(Unknown Source) at com.company.db.dao.LocationDAOImpl.getList(LocationDAOImpl.java:31) [classes:]
at com.company.db.service.LocationDataServiceImpl.getLocations(LocationDataServiceImpl.java:33) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at $Proxy40.getLocations(Unknown Source)    at com.company.something.SomethingSearchController.populateLocationList(SomethingSearchController.java:117) [classes:]
at com.company.something.SomethingSearchController.initForm(SomethingSearchController.java:58) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:391) [urlrewritefilter-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
```

Comment: Please add whole stack trace to your question (can be anonymized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

The two xml files what I had to change now look like this:

springDispatcher-servlet.xml fragment:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.db" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="primary" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
    </bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.company.db.Location</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- Auto-detect entity classes -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

That's all. Now I can use the MySQL DB with Hibernate and JBoss AS 7.

Comment: I also had to add <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />

Comment: That solved my problem after a long night searching dozens of pages